# predict with Multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, r, logistic-regression, predictive-modeling

If I execute the following code I have no problem:

```
require(foreign)
require(nnet)
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

ml <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")
test <- multinom(prog2 ~ ses + write, data = ml)
predict(test, newdata = dses, "probs")
```

but if I try:

```
require(caret)
ml <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")
test <- train(prog2 ~ ses + write,method="multinom" ,data = ml)
predict(test$finalModel, newdata = dses, "probs")
```

it returns `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'sesmiddle' not found`, why?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the error I get and I'm thinking that you left out some code. I get:

```
predict(test$finalModel, newdata = dses, "probs")
Error in as.data.frame(newdata) : object 'dses' not found
```

I don't know why I see this so much, but you should avoid using the `finalModel` object for prediction. `train` is doing some things that the model from `multinom` sin't aware of (such as expanding dummy variables). Try using

```
predict(test, newdata = dses, "probs")
```

and never use `predict(test$finalModel)` again...

Max

Comment: @RobertoDotti, then mark the question as answered (and post your answer if topepo's wasn't what you did)?